# zero element in tensor product of a localization ring and a module

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$. Let $f$ be a non-nilpotent element of $R$ and let $R_f$ be a localization of $R$ by the multiplicative set $\{ f^i \mid i=0,1,2,\dots\}$.

Let $M$ be an $R$-module.

Suppose that there is an element $m\otimes 1$ in $M\otimes_R R_f$ that is zero, i.e., $m\otimes 1=0$.

What I want to show is that there exists $f^n$ such that $f^n m=0$ in $M$.

Here is my attempt.
We have $0=m\otimes 1=m\otimes f^i/f^i=f^im\otimes 1/f^i$ for any $i$.
But I don't know how to go further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Atiyah-Macdonald* has:

[image]

In this case $M\otimes_R R_f\cong M_f$, (for which $m\otimes 1/1\mapsto m/1$).

Now, because of $m\otimes 1/1=0,$ (in $M\otimes_R R_f$), you have $m/1=0$ in $M_f$. So there exists $f^n$ such that $f^n m=0$ in $M$.